# Trying to understand warning messages I get when using babel for react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I have made a simple react rendering function that prints out hello in a div tag with the id of "react-container". The only problem is that I keep getting warning messages in the console like

> **unreachable code after return statement**

or

> **mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial
>   [[Prototype]] value using Object.create**

All of this is coming from the babel-core browser.js script I inserted into the document. I'm trying to figure out what it means, am I doing something wrong, or should I just ignore it

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>REACT 1</title>
    <script src="react-15.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="react-dom-15.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="react-container">

    </div>
<script type="text/babel" >

 ReactDOM.render(<h1>hello</h1>, document.getElementById('react-container'));
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It sounds like you're using some browser plugin that lints javascript code for you, or your browser is giving these warnings by default. What browser are you using, and do you have any debug flags enabled? There is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: I am using firefox, and I don't think I have any debug flags enabled.

Comment: I am not sure you can parse jsx with babel core alone, you need the `babel-preset-react` plugin.

Comment: @Daniel_L well in a tutorial that I am watching there are using this script. I don't know if this plugin you're mentioning is better. Do you use that plugin when you use react?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the default behavior of the Firefox developer console. More advanced debugging environments like the Chrome console don't show warnings like these. You can disable the linting of scripts in Firefox by clicking on this button:

[image]

A "warning" is simply that: A warning that there **might** be a potential issue with the syntax of code. In this case the warnings are harmless, and because they come from third party scripts, there's not much you can do about it. Especially the second one, which is really more of an opinionated code style.